# Stretch content div to fill screen when content is less than whole page | Enjin

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm working on an **enjin** site for a friend and cannot for the life of me understand how to make the page here stretch to fill the whole screen **vertically** if the content does not have enough in it to do it on it's own. I've tried scripts and CSS of a dozen or more solutions and cannot understand how to make it do this because it's not my code, its Enjin's, and I have to work around it.

There are 2 pages in question, one is a standard format page so anything done to it can be done to all pages except the custom one and there will be no problems, and the other is a custom coded page using their HTML module. The key is the same solution is necessary for both but they have different code.

Custom Page: [X](https://142airbornedivision.enjin.com/members) |
Standard Page: [X](https://142airbornedivision.enjin.com/forums)

Simply put I'm asking for a solution here. I tried the flex solution, height 100% with block display, javascript to find the distance between the bottom of the bottom div and the bottom of the monitor and adjust height accordingly, and more. Nothing seems to work. Any help is very gratefully appreciated.

I can provide any more details necessary, just ask.

Comment: Tell me, does adding this code to your css fix your problem? #memberContainer{ width:100% !important }

Comment: @YAHsaves no nothing changes with that

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding what you're asking for then. That code should stretch the #memberContainer div across the entire page which is what I thought you wanted. Can you edit your question to be more specific? Or if you didn't see the #memberContainer div stretch can you tell me how specifically you edited it? It may be a cache issue or something related

Comment: @YAHsaves I added the keyword vertically i realized i forgot the first time. Width is fine as is, I'm trying to get vertically the page to fill if the content is not large enough. In the links provided you can see how the background cuts off and there is a large white block on the bottom spanning the width of the section. the inspector window has this as just void space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is 2 things. First you want to make the div #memberContainer always be at least as tall as the users screen minus the height of your footer.

This can be acomplished with css using the "[vh](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)" unit. The vh unit is defined like this:

> Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*

And the [calc function](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/), as you will need to subtract 100vh (the screen height)  from the height of your footer (180px).

So you need to add this code to your #memberContainer.

```
#memberContainer{min-height: calc(100vh - 180px)}
```

The second thing you need to do is make sure the background image of #memberBlock always covers the entire visible portion of the screen.

The image itself is 1920*1080, which is a standard 16:9 resolution. Assuming you only wanted to target 16:9 screens this would work fine. However to cover mobile phones and all other screens I would recommend you use:

```
#memberBlock{background-size:cover}
```

This makes sure the image will always cover the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have no gap and no content to fill it. There will have to be a gap somewhere.. Your gap is appearing in the middle because the footer is absolutely positioned. If you stop positioning your footer absolutely, the footer will cling to the body-wrap, however, you will still have a gap at the bottom, it just won't look as bad.

```css
.myfooter {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: RGB(20, 20, 20);
    height: 180px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If you really wanted to make it fit the screen, you could give a min-height with a calc of 100vh-FooterHeight

Comment: Am I able to add an empty div of some kind that pushes the footer down or expands the content?

Comment: I wouldn't... Just change "background-color: white;" on the #page-wrap element.

Comment: Also add "min-height: calc(100vh - 180px);" to the body-wrap-3. That's what you want I'm guessing.

Comment: Also Also, by change background white, I mean get rid of it. This will allow your footer to stay at the bottom and REALLY clean up the look by removing the useless whitespace around the content.

Comment: You and @YAHsaves nailed it. Thanks a ton, I cant accept 2 answers and I'm not high enough rep to publically upvote but its been recorded I think

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
```

[image]

There may be other issues with this as i have no idea how mobile or responsive stuff would work for your site specifically but this is one way. You are coupling the BG div to the content div - that is why you are seeing that behavior - you need to make the BG a sibling div of content instead of a parent child relationship then you can have more flexibility on how it works - but for now my option seems to work

Comment: This is the closest to this solution I'm going to get I think because the relationship status you mentioned isn't changeable with Enjin unless I use JS to just remove the contents of the page and let me start from scratch. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: @Church This can be accomplished using pure css as long as you use the calc function